# log4j rollover at restart

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using a log4j FileAppender in my project to collect certain results. When my application restarts, I'd like to keep the previous resultsfile and start a new one. Is that possible?

For example:

- Start application, write results to results.log
- Application ends
- Restart application, write results to results_1.log
- ...

I'v checked out the DailyRollingFileAppender, but that's not really what I need because that will automatically rollover on a certain date setting. I need to rollover when the application restarts.

Answer (score 3):

`Log4j2`'s `RollingFileAppender` has policy called `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy`.

As documentation states:

> The `OnStartupTriggeringPolicy` policy causes a rollover if the log file is older than the current JVM's start time and the minimum file size is met or exceeded.

Example of `xml` configuration (only `Policies`):

```
<Policies>
  <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />                # restart on startup of JVM
  <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />   # restart file if log file reaches 20MB
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />                # restart if currend date don't mach date in log file name     
</Policies>
```

More informations and documentation:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Answer (score 1):

How about having your application set the log file dynamically? You can do this by creating a file appender programatically when your application starts up and attaching it to your current logger.

For example, the following code will create new log files based on the current time. e.g. `results_1336482894.log`, `results_1336486780.log`

```
    Date now = new Date();
    FileAppender myFileAppender = new FileAppender();
    myFileAppender.setName("myFileAppender");
    myFileAppender.setFile("results_" + now.getTime() + ".log");
    myFileAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%t]: %m%n"));
    myFileAppender.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
    myFileAppender.activateOptions();

    Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("name of your logger"); //Or use getRootLogger() instead
    myLogger.addAppender(myFileAppender);
```

Comment: I'd like to keep my code "clean", so I removed all the configuration for log4j to an XML-file before. However, I tried using setFile() as the only programmatically configuration and that works great.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by writing my own appender:

```
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;

/**
   This appender rolls over at program start.
   This is for creating a clean boundary between log data of different runs.
*/
public class RunRolledFileAppender
    extends RollingFileAppender
{
  public RunRolledFileAppender() { }

  @Override
  public void activateOptions() {
    super.activateOptions();
    super.rollOver();
  }

  @Override
  public void rollOver() { }

}
```

Note the ugly disabling of rollOver() was necessary, since the MaxFileSize setting did not work and that Appender otherwise also rolled over every 10MB, which I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ExternallyRolledFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/ExternallyRolledFileAppender.html) and the [`Roller`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/Roller.html) classes to rollover the log file when your application starts up.

Here's an example class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.varia.Roller;
public class Test {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Roller.main(new String[] {"localhost", "9999"});
        log.debug("Started application!");
    }
}
```

And an example `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.varia.ExternallyRolledFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=app.log
log4j.appender.file.Port=9999
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5p: %t: %c: %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
```

Do heed the warning in [`ExternallyRolledFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/ExternallyRolledFileAppender.html):

> Note that the initiator is not authenticated. Anyone can trigger a rollover. In production environments, it is recommended that you add some form of protection to prevent undesired rollovers.

If this does not suit your needs, it should be trivial to create your own similar `Appender` implementation.